# Chop up a Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array which has negative numbers followed by a few positive and then another negative number.

Here is an example

```
arr = np.array([-1, 2, 4, 6, -2, 4, 6, 9, 3, -3, 45, 4, -4, 23, 45, 2])
```

I would like to divide the array so that each negative number and the following positive numbers are on a line each.

```
([-1, 2, 4, 6,
  -2, 4, 6, 9, 3,
  -3, 45, 4,
  -4, 23, 45, 2])
```

How can I do this?

thanks

Comment: It is *really* unclear what you mean. Are you just trying to *print* your array in a specific way?

Comment: Unlike a list of lists, a 2D numpy array cannot be formed from 1D arrays of different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

```
print("([", end="")
last=0
for i in range(1,len(ar)):
  if i < 0:
    print("  "+", ".join(ar[last:i]))
    last=i+1
  elif last = i:
    continue

print(", ".join(ar[last:])+"])")
```